# How can I create a Set with a custom hash function

Tags: swift

I'd like to create a set but I don't want to use the hash function that I've already defined for my object. Is there a way to provide a uniquing/hashing function?

I have an object:

```
class Foo {
   var uuid: UUID
   var name: String

   var hash: Int {
      return uuid.hash
   }
}
```

My object is unique by the uuid. But I would like a set of all Foo's unique by name.

To do this I know of a few options:
1) Create dictionary with key as my choosen unique key and the value of my object, then call `.values`
2) Double for loop with inner loop checking if the key already exists

I assume Set internally is doing something like option 1 above, but I was wondering if there was something swift specific. I could always create an extension to make it one line, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: If you have defined a hash function for your object and you don like it.. just replace it with another implementation? If you are looking for an algorithm, just search online for some hashing function algorithm.

Comment: @progammingBeignner My existing hash is correct for all cases except one where I want to have a unique list with a different key. Why did you vote to close this?

Comment: I didn't vote to close... If that is the case, just implement a new hashing function. There is a lot online.

Comment: @progammingBeignner Oh ok. But how do I implement a new hashing function without effecting the existing hashing function? I want to create a set based on a specific keyPath of my object.

Comment: You will get better answers if you show some relevant code and some clear examples of what you are trying to achieve and fully explain why you think you need a 2nd hash function just for `Set`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, I've edited my question adding some code

Comment: Keep in mind that `Set` requires the object to be Hashable which also means they need to be `Equatable`. Do you have a proper `==` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourClass{
    enum HashChoice{
        case first
        case second
    }

    var hashChoice : HashChoice = .first

    public init(){}
}

extension YourClass : Hashable{
    public var hashValue: Int {
        switch hashChoice{
        case .first:
            // your implementation of first hashValue
        case .second:
            // your implementation of second hasValue
        }
    }

    static func == (lhs: YourClass, rhs: YourClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashvalue == rhs.hasValue
    }
}
```

I don know if I have gotten your question correct.. It sounds rather ambiguous to me.. But if you want to have different hashingFunction, just do what I have shown above.

Comment: Interesting, but I like it. I was hoping that Set had an initializer or something like `Set<T>(hash: (T) -> Int)` and I could just pass a custom function.

Comment: I beleive you are still using the built in Set class rahter than wanting to create one on your own right? You see, Set does not have a definite hashing function.. The hashing function is dependent on the class you pass in.. So you can define any hash function you want.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to provide a uniquing/hashing function?

**No.** Swift 4.2 does let the set provide the hash function, but it looks like `Set` always uses an instance of [`Hasher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hasher), described as: *The universal hash function used by Set and Dictionary.* There's no apparent public interface for setting the hash function used by a given set. (If you're interested in details, [*Swift 4.2 improves Hashable with a new Hasher struct*](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/115/swift-4-2-improves-hashable-with-a-new-hasher-struct) is an interesting read.)

> I would like a set of all Foo's unique by name.

There are probably easier ways than to mess with hash functions. If you mean that you want a set of all Foos that have unique names, you could add the names of all the Foos to an `NSCountedSet`, and then pick out all the names that have a count of 1.

Comment: Does using a NSCountedSet perform better than using a Dictionary?

Comment: You'd need to measure, keeping in mind that the performance may depend on the ratio of unique to non-unique items. But the point is that you seem to be spending a lot of effort to use a standard class in a non-standard way; when you find that something is very difficult with a mature framework, it often means that you should change your approach. At the very least, take the path of least resistance *first*, and optimize later if you need to.

Comment: Oh, I've already finished the feature which prompted me to ask this question. I continued in my SO question here to learn so if there was a better way. If every answer is "take the path of least resistance" then no one would learn anything and we'd all be at step 0 using the basics we learned in grade school.